# Whats the difference between stateless and connection-less?

Tags: http

Whats the difference between stateless and connection-less ?
Also, what are the uses of these and the uses of their opposites (stafeful and connection-ful) ?

Comment: These are very broad concepts used with client-server interactions, and I have flagged to close "As too Broad".  I would suggest instead of posting a question here that you use google and investigate each of the terms you used individually.

Comment: I've read articles on wiki about both concepts and to be honest they seem to be the same. I've never heard about this "connectionless" thing before and I find it redundant. But maybe I miss something so I'm upvoting the question.

Answer (score 9):

For "connection-less", the more accurate term should be "Not Connection-Oriented".

In any communication, there are 3 stages: start, interaction, end. The concept "Connection" focus on "start" and "end", while the concept "State" focus on "interaction".

If one communication protocol is "**Connection-Oriented**", it means real data can only be transferred after connection is established, and no data can be transferred after the connection is destroyed -- In telephone communication, we can talk to other people only if they pickup the phone, and can do nothing if they hangup.

If one communication protocol is "**Not Connection-Oriented**", it means real data can be sent whenever you want to. There is no "start" or "end" stage, only "interaction" -- In telegraph communication, we can send message directly.

If one communication protocol is "**Stateful**", it means in "interaction" stage, at least one communication side (client/server) will remember the state of opposite side -- In TCP communication, sequence number is stored and managed is both sides.

If one communication protocol is "**Stateless**", it means in "interaction" stage, no state information is stored in either side. All message is sent in independent way -- In HTTP communication, server doesn't remember the state of client, all HTTP requests are sent independently.

Thus, these are 2 totally different concept. We can have:

- "Connection-Oriented Stateful" protocol: TCP
- "Not Connection-Oriented Stateless" protocol: UDP, HTTP
- "Connection-Oriened Stateless" protocol: In telephone call, after opposite pickup, send multiple independent messages.
- "Not Connection-Oriented Stateful" protocol: In telegraph communication, send multiple highly related and dependent messages.

Here are some "stateless connection" protocol in computer science world:

- http://www.tcs.hut.fi/old/papers/aura/aura-nikander-icics97.ps
- http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/egs/papers/trickles-tocs.pdf